# How to use _.reduce only on some first elements of the array

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I make _.reduce on all elements of my array,unfortunately sometimes the array is just too big.

I want to make reduce on only constant number of elements from the array.

What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: You can use [`_.slice`](https://lodash.com/docs#slice)

Comment: @hege_hegedus that's "lodash", not "underscore" ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.slice` to make a (temporary) copy of the first `n` elements of the array:

```
_.reduce(myArray.slice(0, n), ...);
```

If there are less than `n` elements in the array it'll just use all of them.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [**_.first**](http://underscorejs.org/#first) to get the the number of items you want to reduce:

```
// reduce the first 100 items in the array
var result = _.reduce( _.first(data, 100), fn, memo)
```